# apache http server - deleting a file upon recieving a POST request

Tags: apache, post

is this possible with apache http server? i wish to delete a local xml file upon recieving a post request from an another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with PHP (or any other sript language, your apache server supports).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if ($_POST['var']) unlink ('/path/to/file.xml');
?>
```

But you have to make sure then the POST request is sent to this PHP file. Do you know the URL the POST is send to?

Comment: yeah, actually im working with two PCs now, so the URL for the POST is sent to the one that is hosting the apache server , <http://ipaddress/file.xml>

Comment: Is http://ipaddress/file.xml the URL you access via POST? If you like to use the PHP approach you should rather access http://ipaddress/file.php if that is possible.

Comment: what does var in ($_POST['var']) mean

Comment: If you access http://ipaddress/file.php?var=file.xml then $_POST['var'] will be 'file.xml'

Comment: im getting a Notice: Undefined index: var in C:\phptests\Test.php on line 2 when i try http://127.0.0.1/Test.php?var=file.xml

Comment: my php file only has that 3 lines of code that u posted tho :\

Comment: You can ignore notices in PHP. I modified my code above, so this notice will not be shown anymore: error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); Which file is it you like to unlink? You shuold replace '/path/to/file.xml' by that files path

Comment: I really hope you're careful to avoid allowing arbitrary deletion. Either that or let us POST to http://where.ever/file.php?var=/etc/passwd and kiss your OS goodbye. :-)